# Passing value another page

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android. And write this program but get error.

```
public class First1Activity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public final static String x= "com.example.my.p";
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    public void mess(View view) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(First1Activity.this,DisMess.class);
        EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String m= edittext.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(x, m);
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t.setText(m);

            First1Activity.this.startActivity(intent);


    }
    public class DisMess extends Activity{

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(First1Activity.x);
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTextSize(40);
            textView.setText(message);
            setContentView(textView);

        }

    }
```

Now i get Error like::::::

**Application has stop working...**

I got error in line :***First1Activity.this.startActivity(intent);***

pls help

Comment: add logcat if `Application has stop working...`

Comment: Can you confirm DisMess calss is added in menfiest .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have declared DisMess activity in manifest.

I have modified your code slightly.

```
public class First1Activity extends Activity {

public final static String key= "com.example.my.p";
private Context context;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    context=First1Activity.this;

}
public void mess(View view) {

    EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 

    String m= edittext.getText().toString();       
    t.setText(m);   

    Intent intent=new Intent(context,DisMess.class); 
    intent.putExtra(x, m);
    startActivity(intent);
}


  public class DisMess extends Activity{

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(First1Activity.x);
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTextSize(40);
            textView.setText(message);
            setContentView(textView);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in activity 1-

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
i.putExtra("Value1", "This value one for ActivityTwo ");
i.putExtra("Value2", "This value two ActivityTwo");
 startActivity(i);
```

In activity 2 - in onCreate finction

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras == null) {
        return;
        }
// Get data via the key
String value1 = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
if (value1 != null) {
    // Do something with the data
}
```

================

in your code

Comment: ``Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);`` there should be an getApplicationContext() instead of this

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(First1Activity.this,DisMess.class);
EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String m= edittext.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra("x", m);
```

AND

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra("x");
```